# Problems with qiskit-terra: missing members of instance QuantumCircuit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I have installed a Python 3.7.2, download anaconda and visual studio code. Install Qiskit SDK 0.5.3. But when I launch my first test program from https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra I received a couple of messages like

```
{
"message": "Instance of 'QuantumCircuit' has no 'h' member",
"message": "Instance of 'QuantumCircuit' has no 'cx' member",
"message": "Instance of 'QuantumCircuit' has no 'measure' member",
}
```

What I do wrong?

This is my code:

```
from qiskit import *
q = QuantumRegister(2)
c = ClassicalRegister(2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
qc.h(q[0])
qc.cx(q[0], q[1])
qc.measure(q, c)
backend_sim = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = execute(qc, backend_sim).result()
print(result.get_counts(qc))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was at linter.

It's necessary to add

```
 "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=E1101"
    ]
```

to the `settings.json`.

Comment: disabling linting is not necessarily a good idea, as you also lose potentially useful messages. If the linting is not detecting the methods of `qc` it might be because the shell used by vscode in the background is not using the python distribution/environment in which qiskit is installed

Answer (score 4):

These messages pop up in the linter due to the way gates are dynamically added as circuit attributes in Qiskit Terra.  They can safely be ignored. In a future update of Terra these warnings will disappear.